# Getting data from anormal object

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I'm new in Angular and created a app with Firebase backend (real-time database). I'm getting these type of data:
[given data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgjbw.png)

I want to get the value for Firstname and Lastname, but I don't know how to access it. I've tried something like

```
    onRowClicked(data: any) {
        let y = data.settings;
        console.log(y);
      }
```

or something like

```
    onRowClicked(data: any) {
        let y = data.settings[0].Firstname;
        console.log(y);
      }
```

But I can't get these value. What do I wrong?
Can you please help me?

I've tried to cast it into array, but that doesn't work. Then I've tried to iterate it via forEach, but then I get the message, that forEach is not a funktion on this type :/

Comment: You can iterate over object properties by : for (const item in data.settings){}

Comment: Thank you so much. I've tried it and now I'm getting only the key. How can I access the subitems?

Comment: use data.settings[item] to get the value